# How to insert a line in python to make code easier to read

Tags: python

I have some python code. In order to shorten the rest of the script, I have placed all the values into something like this:

```
Data = 14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14
```

This is of course, hard to read, so I then wanted to add comments.

```
Data = 14,14,14 #1 14,14,14 #2 14,14,14 #3 14,14,14 #4
```

This of course did not work, as the comments commented out everything else.
So I wanted to do this:

```
Data = 
14,14,14, #1
14,14,14, #2
14,14,14, #3
14,14,14, #4
```

This gives me a SyntaxError.
Does anyone know if this is possible?
And if so, how to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: If you downvote this, could you please give a reason why? Duplicate? Not clear? Poor question?

Comment: I complete agree. I do not see anything wrong in this question..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use parens to break statements up over multiple lines:

```
Data = (
    14, 14, 14,  # 1 
    14, 14, 14,  # 2 
    14, 14, 14,  # 3 
    14, 14, 14,  # 4
)
```

Note that you can multiply tuples; if 1 thru 4 are identical, it's simpler IMO to write:

```
Data = (14, 14, 14) * 4  # 1 thru 4
```

Answer (score -1):

You miss the commas:

```
Data = 
14,14,14, #1
14,14,14, #2
14,14,14, #3
14,14,14 #4
```

Comment: Doesn't work (yet). Error highlights the area after `=`